# Would it be possible to combine gtx 1060 and gtx 970 in a single rig?

Tags: mining

I have a two gtx1060 6g working, i have seen that the gtx790 is cheaper and the performence is quite similare. i am thinking of adding 4 gtx970 in the same rig.

would it be possible??